# Orbot cannot connect to the Tor network through bridges

Tags: help, orbot

In orbot software.
I cannot use obfs3 bridges to connect to the Tor network.
This is the logs.
Orbot shows that it is successfully connected to the Tor network but I'm sure it didn't.
So what's the problem? 
`logs`

```
Orbot 正在启动...
tor: PRE: Is binary exec? true
polipo: PRE: Is binary exec? true
obfsclient: PRE: Is binary exec? true
xtables: PRE: Is binary exec? true
Orbot 正在启动...
updating torrc custom configuration...
success.
Reading control port config file: /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/control.txt
Connecting to control port: 44651
SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
Orbot 正在启动...
SUCCESS - authenticated to control port.
adding control port event handler
SUCCESS added control port event handler
NOTICE: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
Local SOCKS port: 9050
NOTICE: Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:38781 
NOTICE: Closing old Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:38781 
Local TransProxy port: 9040
NOTICE: Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400 
NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:36017 
NOTICE: Closing old DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:36017 
Local DNSPort port: 9040
Tor started; process id=31266
updating settings in Tor service
Starting polipo process
SUCCESS - authenticated to control port.
adding control port event handler
SUCCESS added control port event handler
发现当前已存在 Tor 进程...
正在启动 Tor 客户端... 完成。
NOTICE: Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges 
Privoxy 当前所用的端口：8118
Polipo process id=31276
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
```

Answer (score 2):

Close and restart orbot. Make sure the format of obfs3 bridge is correct.

obfs3 works in mainland China, but those bridges you added might be blocked. If you see warning messages like 'TTL expired', then try adding more bridges.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't ever connected. Seems like GFW knows you are connecting to Tor ( If you are in mainland China and using public bridges and these bridges has been detected ). Try other bridges.